# Laravel Model - cast of time

Tags: php, laravel, date, format, php-carbon

Is there a way to automatically cast a model's attribute whose type is `time` in the same way we do with `date` or `datetime`?

I know about mutators, but I wonder if it can be done in a cleaner way, like using `$casts` property.

Comment: Just add those as `protected $dates = ['nameofdatefield', 'nameofyourdatetimefield', 'nameoftimefield];` in your model.

Comment: Does not work, as mentioned. My field type if on the format `H:i:s` and I want it as `H:i`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.6, it is possible to use `$casts` to specify custom formats for dates & times. ([relevant docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-casting))

You'd want something like this:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:H:i',
];
```